# How to move rich snippets from subdomain to main domain

Tags: wordpress

I have a subdomain with Woocommerce and many products. I am trying to add reviews (preferably via Rich snippet plugin to keep it simple) that the user can fill in under the product but it will appear on the main site. If this isn't possible, then maybe just a link from the subdomain right into the rich snippet form on the main domain?
Right now I am using Woocommerce reviews but the reviews are not indexed since the subdomain is set to no index. I have great reviews that are wasted since they aren't indexed.
Even if I can't use my old reviews I would like a solution to get new reviews on the main domain.

Comment: So you need to export/import your reviews from old site to new site?

Comment: I would like to import old reviews as well but more importantly looking for an automatic solution for future reviews.

Comment: Can you provide me which reviews with plugin link or site link?

Comment: thanks. http://www.custom.101giftcertificatetemplates.com/shop/mothers-day/mothers-day-gift-certificate-template-15-2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $wpdb to fetch and store the reviews from old site to new site.

Reviews are stored in `wp_comments` table via product ID , you need to write a query via `$wpdb` to fetch the product reviews by checking the `post_type` is `product` from `wp_posts` table and then collect all the reviews via `wp_comments` table.

Class reference : [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

You can use get_results to retrive and query to insert the data from $wpdb global element like the following.

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" , ARRAY_A );

$myrows = $wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO.." );
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Is it possible to get results from all product IDs in a particular category?

Comment: Yes , you can get that via : wp_term_relationships , check object id is product id and term_taxonomy_id is your category id